# Consulta o Insert que muestre la fecha y hora actual

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

Estoy haciendo una consulta de una tabla que tiene que mostrar los registros con la fecha y hora actual, pero lo que me muestra son las fechas del día siguiente.

Por ejemplo: Quiero que me muestre la fecha actual en el Grid por ejemplo 4/11/2019 12:00:00 pm, no en el dia 5/11/2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que estoy utlizando en VB Net:

```
 Public Sub Gd_perfil()

    Dim Usuario As String
    Dim Tabla As String
    Dim Observaciones As String
    Dim dt As DataTable

    vm_sql = "Insert [KNTB_Bitacora] (Usuario, Fecha_Ingreso, Modulo, Observaciones) values ('Kevin',GetDate(),'Intereses Devengados Mayor',' Invierte a los empresarios las ganancias que obtuvieron en cada negocio  ')"


    sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)
    GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()

End Sub
```

Esta es para ver toda la tabla

```
 Public Sub Gd_perfil1()
    Dim fechaIni As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim fechaFin As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dim dt As DataTable

    ' Intervalo para las fechas  
    vm_sql = "Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  Fecha_Ingreso Between CONVERT(datetime,'" + fechaIni + " ') And CONVERT(datetime,'" + fechaFin + "' )"
    sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)
    GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Gd_perfil1()

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub
```

En el SQL lo muestra asi

```
Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  Fecha_Ingreso Between '20191104'   And   '20191105'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al usar la misma fecha se mostró eso

```
  Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  Fecha_Ingreso Between '20191104'   And   '20191104'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo cual es el error si estas haciendo un between.

Comment: al hacer un insert, me muestra las fechas del dia siguiente, no me muestra las actuales

Comment: los insert no devuelven una consulta. Al hacer insert no se como haces para que muestre algo...

Comment: tu metodo con "problemas" (supongamos) es Traer_info_sql que no sabemos que hace

Comment: son las acciones que utilicé para sql  en VB `Dim sql As New AccesoDatosSQL
    Dim vm_tabla As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim vm_sql As String = "" `

Comment: A ver.. un insert no devuelve datos. nunca. o sea, no puede traerte nada tu insert. Ese metodo te esta devolviendo algo desde algun lado, y seria interesante verlo para entender que pasa. por favor si tenes que agregar info usa el boton [edit]

Comment: el between lo uso para que muestre todas las fechas, pero cuando hago el insert, no muestra la misma fecha de hoy

Comment: por ejemplo en el sql se refleja asi  `Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  Fecha_Ingreso Between '20191104'   And   '20191105'` pero no muestra la misma fecha `'20191104'   And   '20191104'`

Comment: Ahora entiendo tu pregunta. pero tene en cuenta que no se que tiene que ver el insert en la misma, y es todo un problema de como haces el query a las fechas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema amigo es que el campo fecha en la BD no es solo una fecha, es una fecha y hora por ende si le preguntas fecha = '20191104' es falso porque fecha es igual a '20191104 10:56:11.320'.

Para solucionar ello se me ocurre que puedes convertir tu campo fecha de la base de datos en smalldatetime y luego compararlo.

```
Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE cast(Fecha_Ingreso as smalldatetime) Between '20191104' And '20191105'
```

Si por ABC motivo no funciona, agrega los separadores a la fecha para que quede con formato año mes dia

```
Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE cast(Fecha_Ingreso as smalldatetime) Between '2019-11-04' And '2019-11-05'
```

Comment: No me los muestra los 2

Comment: Perdón mi error, debe ser entre el 04-11 y 05-11, corrijo el código.

Comment: Pero no habrá ningún problema si no utilizo la misma fecha por ejemplo, si quiero incluir la hora de la fecha de ayer para que me muestre la misma fecha con la hora, se podrá mostrar en la tabla?

Comment: @Fopa, si vas a tener el problema por las horas. cuando quieras consultar un solo dia tenes que tomar desde el inicio del dia al consultar, hasta el inicio del dia siguiente...

Comment: Bueno Entonces lo haré así, yo pensaba que con las horas por ejemplo 12 o 24 horas, se podría mostrar esa única fecha, pero para que me las muestre, tengo que mostrarlo al día siguiente.